# Ubuntu with Ipod Touch 6th Gen - Copied songs don't show on device

Tags: music, rhythmbox, banshee, ipod

My wife bought both of my daughters iPod Touch 6th Gens for Christmas.

I am able to see the Ipods - they show up in Thunar, Clementine, Rhythmbox, and Banshee.

I used Banshee to send 50 songs to the device.  They seemed to sync fine, and I can see them show up in Thunar.

However, after ejecting, the iPod does not see them or show them in the library.  Do the 6th gens store the files in a different folder than older iPods?  Do I need to manually move some files around?

Is there a guide somewhere for the 6th gen Touch?  If there is, I cannot find it online.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: I had the same problem with a 5th gen.  Ended up setting up a virtual windoze machine to run iTunes, could not get it to work any other way.

Comment: It seems to me that your music is already on your iphone but it won't allow you to play it, I would say is more an apple related question about how to play music without using itunes. Maybe you want to ask here http://apple.stackexchange.com/